# shared preferences returns location not int

Tags: android

I am using the shared preferences editor to store numbers to save and use in another class with in my project, this is my source to save the data:

```
public void overallEditor(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
        editor.putInt("winsOverall", winsOverall);
        editor.putInt("losesOverall", losesOverall);
        editor.putInt("tiesOverall", tiesOverall);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

this is my source that retrieves the data:

```
private void getStats() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        bestStreakStatsi = someData.getInt("newBestStreak", 0);
        winsOverall = someData.getInt("winsOverall", 0);
        tiesOverall = someData.getInt("tiesOverall", 0);
        losesOverall = someData.getInt("losesOverall", 0);
    }
```

### What is happening

[image]

this is my source from my first class, if you need more from my source i can provide it but i cut out what is irrelevant:

```
int wins, ties, loses, choice, streak, bestStreak, z, winsOverall, losesOverall, tiesOverall;

    private void refresh(){
            winrep.setText(w + wins);
            loserep.setText(l + loses);
            tierep.setText(t + ties);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
            editor.putInt("winsp", wins);
            editor.putInt("losesp", loses);
            editor.putInt("tiesp", ties);
            editor.putInt("streakp", streak);
            editor.commit();
            overallEditor();
        }
        public void overallEditor(){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
            editor.putInt("winsOverall", winsOverall);
            editor.putInt("losesOverall", losesOverall);
            editor.putInt("tiesOverall", tiesOverall);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

this is where it should be retrieving the ints:

```
public class stats extends Activity{
    public static String filename = "stats";
    TextView bestStreakStats, overallWins, overallLoses, overallTies;
    int bestStreakStatsi, winsOverall, losesOverall, tiesOverall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats);
        initizialize();
        getStats();
        displayStats();
    }
    private void displayStats() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bestStreakStats.setText("You best winning streak: \t" + bestStreakStatsi);
        overallWins.setText("Your overall wins: \t" + overallWins);
        overallLoses.setText("Your overall loses: \t" + overallLoses);
        overallTies.setText("Your overall ties: \t" + overallTies);
    }
    private void getStats() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        bestStreakStatsi = someData.getInt("newBestStreak", 0);
        winsOverall = someData.getInt("winsOverall", 0);
        tiesOverall = someData.getInt("tiesOverall", 0);
        losesOverall = someData.getInt("losesOverall", 0);
    }
    private void initizialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bestStreakStats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBestStreakStats);
        overallWins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOverallWins);
        overallLoses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOverallLoses);
        overallTies = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOverallTies);
    }
}
```

Comment: returns location...? What proof do we see of that here? Also instead your method name of overallEditor() makes no sense. Should be something like updateUserStatsPreference(int[] gamestate).

Comment: @JoxTraex http://imgur.com/WFRdT

Comment: @JoxTraex I don't really want to play around with arrays right now, maybe later in development but thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: You **REALLY** need to fix your naming conventions. The reason this is happening is because you're displaying the wrong object. @macmitterder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are referencing the wrong variable. You are saying.

```
overallWins.setText("Your overall wins: \t" + overallWins);
```

But I think it should be:

```
overallWins.setText("Your overall wins: \t" + winsOverall);
```

The same thing goes for the rest of the `.setText`. See if that helps.

Comment: Ideally he should not be retrieving his text from the TextView, but the integer value. I think this was what was intended @0gravity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is most likely because you are doing this

```
[TextView Object].getText();
```

This is incorrect, it should be:

```
[TextView Object].getText().toString();
```

### Update

You **REALLY** need to fix your naming conventions. The reason this is happening is because you're displaying the wrong object in your displayStats() method.

for some advice, I'd recommend this naming convention for your TextViews

```
TextView tx_[somename];
```

and your values

```
int value_[somename]
```

Comment: im not retrieving text though, I'm retrieving ints

Comment: please update your original post with respective code lines. The Objects  that you are using for these preference included as well. @macmittereder

Comment: TY! got it and ya, deffinetly going to have to change that

Comment: Don't forget to set as the answer if it solved you issue @macmittereder !